# How do I redirect these water currents to get my loot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've created a mob trap using a canal and lava. The trap works fine, and I'm getting lots of mobs into it.

I am trying to automatically flow the loot via water into a different section of the trap. Here's the problem - while creating the water flow, I accidentally modified the water currents. Now the loot sometimes gets stuck in a part of the trap. If the loot is in any other part of the trap, it flows down perfectly.

Have a look at this image to see what I mean:

[image]

In the second image you'll see how there's a weird 'waterfall current' created.

[image]

How do I fix this? :(

Comment: Have you tried removing all the water sources, waiting for the water to recede and then replacing them? If you get the same problem again you'll need to fix your channels.

Comment: Water never works well when it drops over one block in height. I would simply alter your ground so the water travels two blocks across then one block down.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Water sometimes does strange things. As [Kurley](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/756/kurley) has commented, your best bet is to block up the waterfall, or remove the watersources, and replace them. Make sure the 'lip' that the water is flowing over is straight, it looks from your image like it might not be. Make sure there is no overhang, and make sure that there are no other water sources at this level than the water coming down from the waterfall.

Comment: I'm going to try this and let you know if it works. Thanks!